# 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

executing this statement :

```
SELECT  *
FROM userauth@MSBN
WHERE Roles 
LIKE '%msbnadmin%';
```

returns this response :

```
ORA-00904: "ROLES": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 7
```

In workbench when directly connected with @msbn it works exactly like i put it here.

Comment: Is roles a reserved word? Try `"Roles"`.

Comment: Imho. You don't have roles column in target table.  `select * from dual where abc = 'a';` the query produces the same error.

Comment: I do have those, but Roles is a reserved keyword so i needed to escape them. Rahul Tripathi's answer did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to [escape `Roles`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) and try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM userauth@MSBN
WHERE "Roles" 
LIKE '%msbnadmin%';
```

`Roles` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle. So you need to escape it using double quotes `""`